# how to pass array used in function to the dynamically allocated array of main?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>    
using namespace std;

char *fun(const char* a)
{
        int size=strlen(a);

        char* str=new char[12];

        for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        {
                str[i]=a[size-i-1];
        }

        str[size-1]='\0';

        return str;
}

main()
{
        int i=0;

        char a[11]={'a','y','u','s','h','r','i','k','h','r','a'};

        char *p=new char[11];

        p=fun(a);

        for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
        {
                cout<<p[i]<<" ";
        }

        delete(ptr);
}
```

//having some troubles using array p in the main here please help.

Comment: Please format your code correctly, and don't put an extra blank line after _every_ line. And _having some troubles using array p_ is not a problem statement.

Comment: `char *p=new char[11];

   p=fun(a);` - This is a nice recipe for a memory leak. You allocate some memory and then immediately make `p` point elsewhere, leaving no way to deallocate that memory.

Comment: having problem...that is known...what problem...that be unbeknownst.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `std::string`?

Comment: This is not doing anything, making new arrays and initializing them with nothing.

Comment: Only string literals are zero-terminated.

Comment: `delete(ptr);` I dont see ptr is declared in your code. Atleast please add some compiling code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues:

---

Here the `a` array is not NUL terminated, therefore `strlen` cannot be used on it in `fun`:

```
char a[11]={'a','y','u','s','h','r','i','k','h','r','a'};
```

---

Here you are allocating a fixed size of 12, but you need a dynamic size depending on the length of the string:

```
char* str=new char[12];
```

---

Then:

```
str[size-1]='\0';
```

should be:

```
str[size] = '\0';
```

otherwise your resulting string will miss the last character.

---

In main:

```
char *p=new char[11];
```

is pointless because you assign `p` right after with `p=fun(a);`.

---

You call `delete(ptr);`, but there is no `ptr`.

---

And finally you should also `#include <string.h>` be sure that `strlen` is defined, but one some platforms it compiles also without `#include <string.h>`.

---

You probably want this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char *fun(const char* a)
{
  int size = strlen(a);
  char* str = new char[size + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    str[i] = a[size - i - 1];
  }

  str[size] = '\0';
  return str;
}

int main()
{
  char a[] = "ABCDE";    
  char *p = fun(a);    
  int size = strlen(p);

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    cout << p[i] << " ";
  }

  delete[] p;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `str[size - 1] = '\0';` be `str[size] = '\0';`?

Comment: When I try to compile the above code, I got strlen not declared error,   am I missing anything here? 
`g++ cc.cpp 
cc.cpp: In function ‘char* fun(const char*)’:
cc.cpp:8:22: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
   int size = strlen(a);
                      ^
cc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cc.cpp:24:22: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
   int size = strlen(p);`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer no, I'm on a different platform and there `<string>` probably includes `<string.h>`, just add `#include <string.h>` should do the job.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer It compiles on Visual Studio, try [including `<cstring>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)